# Comparing html element with a file loaded with .get

Tags: jquery

I have a div that I want to repeatedly update the content of from a file on a server, using `setInterval`. I only wanted to actually update the content if it's changed, so I tried the following:

```
$.get('online.txt', function(result){
  if ($('#update').html() != result) {
    $('#update').html(result);
    updatecount++;
    $('#logcount').html(updatecount);
  }
});
```

However, the ticker continually updates, indicating that my comparison operation is failing. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but it's not obvious to me. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you print out `result`?  If I were you then I'd `alert(result + "<br><br>" + $('#update').html());` so you can compare the two results yourself.

Comment: Please post the output of `console.log($('#update').html())` as well as the result of `console.log(result)`.

Comment: @Jolyon: Without seeing what `#update` is, i.e div, span, input, etc.. it is not easy to tell why `html()` is null.

Comment: Ah, thank you for bring the console.log commands to my attention, Francois. The error seems to be arising because the file I'm loading contains html code, including `<br />`. However, the `.html()` returns this as `<br>` instead, and therefore there is a discrepancy (at least, using Firefox). I guess I will need to redesign things somewhat?

Comment: Sorry Francois - I had just copied your text in to my file without renaming to the appropriate variable, which was why I was seeing null. I deleted my previous comment when I realised this is what had happened.

Comment: @Jolyon: The main thing is you are getting closer to the root of the problem :)

Comment: Thanks :-) I decided to solve this problem by loading a hidden div `<div id="hidden" style="display: none;"></div>`, and loading the results into that first, before comparing. `$('#hidden').html(result);`, followed by `if ($('#update').html() != $('#hidden').html()) {`. This seems to do the job I was after.